# How does one use beautiful soup to scrape a table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-tables

So, I have this jenkins server container and I want to scrape the stage view table from the jobs page and dump the values into a spreadsheet. However, I can't seem to locate the table?

[image]

According to the inspect document, I search for a table class, however the only result I get is "None".

[image]

Is there a proper way to scrap it with beautiful soup?

It should be a simple scrape right?

```
page = browser.get(jhost)
    print(page.status_code)

    # Dump test data
    page = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    container = soup.select("table", {"class": "jobsTable"})
```

Comment: If the table is generated by JS, bs4 won't see it.

Comment: maybe server has  `API for programmers` and then you could get data as `csv` or `json` without scraping.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to pull the data one build at a time, but that would take a million requests to jenkins....  I am going to try with phantomjs and see if that is going to work better.